# Javascript not working Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017

My current code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App1</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test">Content goes here!</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script>  
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Working";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I debug on Visual Studio 2017 the html works fine.
[Picture of code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx9j5.png)

However, clicking the button does nothing. No error messages, just nothing happens. If I copy and paste the code into a text document, format it as an html and test that in Chrome, everything works fine. Any idea why this happens?

Edit: It was made as a Blank JavaScript App if that changes anything

Comment: No errors in the dev console? Are you sure?

Comment: If you run it in Visual Studio, right click the page and do View Source, do you see anything strange? Just seems like there's something missing here.

Comment: Can you try to add type= text/javascript. May work.

Comment: @biswajit-rout `text/javascript` is the default in browsers.

Comment: Yes right . Your.code is perfect but I think this migjt be an issue. Better to acces the id of the button and add the code on button click. I think this is the better way. Else you can use jquery or angular.

Comment: @doutriforce There are no errors. It just acts as if the JS did not exist

Comment: @biswajit-rout use the ID like in Scott's answer?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why that would be the case. There is nothing in your code that would indicate an issue, other than it is possible that the file open in your browser is NOT the file you are editing in Visual Studio.

Make sure that, from Visual Studio, you right click on the source code and choose to run the page in a browser.

I can say that you should not be using inline HTML event attributes (`onclick`, etc.), [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) why.

Try reformatting your code to use modern, standards-based code like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App1</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test">Content goes here!</p>
    <button id="btn">Try it</button>
    <script>  
        // Get DOM references
        var p = document.getElementById("test");
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    
        btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
    
        function myFunction() {
            p.innerHTML = "Working";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```